# Teradata Query Using Dapper C#

Tags: c#, .net, teradata, dapper

I am trying to dynamically query a Teradata database using Dapper but am having some issues. Here is the code:

```
// model variable is the parameter passed in with search information
using (IDbConnection con = new TdConnection(connection.GetConnectionString()))
{
    var builder = new SqlBuilder();
    var selector = builder.AddTemplate($"SELECT * FROM Temp_Table /**where**/");

    if (model.Id != 0)
    {
        builder.Where("Id = ?", new { model.Id });
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Employee_Id))
    {
        builder.Where("Employee_Id = ?", new { model.Employee_Id });
    }

    var data= con.Query<TableModel>(selector.RawSql, model).ToList();
    return data;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> [Teradata Database] [3939] There is a mismatch between the number of
>   parameters specified and the number of parameters required.

I have used very similar code to query DB2 which worked just fine; what do I need to do differently with Teradata?

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it appears to be falling through and not adding any "where" condition. Try to structure it in such a way that if it falls through then add 1=1 or a Teradata equivalent if that doesn't work.

I'm unfamiliar with the `SqlBuilder()` class; but if you have a way of seeing if there aren't any Where constraints added, then to add a generic one. Or, a dirtier way would be to keep a `bool` reference and check at the end.

### Update

Try passing in the parameters:

```
var data= con.Query<TableModel>(selector.RawSql, selector.Parameters).ToList();
```

Comment: It's adding the where class just fine - the selector.RawSQL is "SELECT * FROM DMMKP.RCRG_EMAIL_CAPTURE WHERE Id = ?" when Id is just passed in

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem. I think you need to pass the parameters instead of the model.

Comment: I noticed that right before you commented. It's weird though, I have very similar code working querying DB2 where I don't pass in the parameters. Not sure why it isn't the same in this case.

Comment: I'd imagine it's the way it's mapping the objects. It appears to be expected an object of objects.. instead of just the model (singular object). Here's the source if you want to get into the weeds: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper.SqlBuilder/SqlBuilder.cs

Answer (score 1):

Managed to figure it out. Changed the line for getting the data to:

```
var data= con.Query<TableModel>(selector.RawSql, selector.Parameters).ToList();
```

Not sure why passing in the model worked just fine in my DB2 version but not this Teradata version.